# Exibir valores de vetor imaginário com aritmética de ponteiros

Tags: c, c++

Boa tarde !
Estou fazendo o seguinte exercício !

-Crie um programa que contenha um array de inteiros contendo 5 elementos. Utilizando
apenas aritmética de ponteiros, leia esse array do teclado e imprima o dobro de cada
valor lido.

Resolucao

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int x[5];
    int *v=NULL;
    v=&x;


     for (int i;i<5;i++){
        int y;
        scanf("%i",&y);
        *v=y;
        v++;

    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Valor %i - Posicao %i\n",*v,v);
    printf("Valor %i - Posicao %i\n",*v+1,v+1);
    printf("Valor %i - Posicao %i\n",*v+2,v+2);
    printf("Valor %i - Posicao %i\n",*v+3,v+3);
    printf("Valor %i - Posicao %i\n",*v+4,v+4);
}
```

Minha duvida e a seguinte:
Quando eu crio um "FOR" ou outra variável inteira para criar outro laço as variáveis e posicionamento de memoria ficam todo estranho. Eu acredito que isso aconteça porque quando crio outra variável eu digo oque quero salvar e não onde quero salvar na memoria, como indico a posição da memoria que quero salvar?

Outra duvida porque quando crio um vetor forçado sem o [] da erro? Eu estou mexendo com posicionamento de memoria, então não deveria aceitar quando coloco a posição do valor referencia do tipo int + 1? Se ficou difícil de entender e só apagar o colchetes da variável x no começo e executar, ai vai da erro na segunda vez.

***Resumindo*** Como faço para colocar esses printf no final dentro de um laço!

Comment: Aqui: `printf("Valor %i - Posicao %i\n",*v+1,v+1);` não deveria ser: `printf("Valor %i - Posicao %i\n",*(v+1), v+1);`? Idem demais posições.

Answer (score 0):

> Minha duvida e a seguinte: Quando eu crio um "FOR" ou outra variável inteira para criar outro laço as variáveis e posicionamento de memoria ficam todo estranho.

O que está acontecendo é que você está lendo a memoria além dos 5 elementos do array.

Você pode corrigir isso apontando novamente o ponteiro para o começo do array.

Você não deve usar o operador **&** para obter o endereço de um array, porque o nome de um array já é um endereço.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  // aloca a memoria para os 5 elementos.
  int valores[5];

  // aponta para o inicio do array.
  int *ptr_valores = valores;

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    printf("Insira um número: ");
    scanf("%d", ptr_valores);

    // incrementa o ponteiro para o proximo elemento.
    ++ptr_valores;
  }

  // aponta para o inicio do array novamente.
  ptr_valores = valores;

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    // imprime o dobro de cada elemento.
    printf("%d\n", (*ptr_valores) * 2);

    // incrementa o ponteiro para o próximo elemento.
    ++ptr_valores;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

> Outra duvida porque quando crio um vetor forçado sem o [] da erro?

Não sei o que você quer dizer com vetor forçado, mas se você retirar os [] de uma variável, você estará criando uma variável normal e não um array.

> Eu estou mexendo com posicionamento de memoria, então não deveria aceitar quando coloco a posição do valor referencia do tipo int + 1?

Na aritmética de ponteiros quando um ponteiro tem o seu valor adicionado ou subtraído por outro valor acontece o seguinte calculo:

endereço = endereço inicial + (tamanho do tipo do ponteiro em bytes * n).

Portanto, se um ponteiro ptr do tipo int aponta para 0x0, ao fazer ptr + 1, será feito o seguinte cálculo:

ptr = ptr + (4 * 1)

Agora, ptr aponta para o endereço 0x4, assumindo que int tenha 4 bytes.